# Subdomain working fine with http and not working with https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, cpanel

Recently I have installed ssl certificate on my website. After the ssl certificates have been installed ,I found that my subdomain is not working properly. I will address my subdomain as 'xxxx'and main domain as 'primary'. The main domain works well with http as well as https. Now the subdomain works well with http, but with https://xxxx.primary.com delivers me the main site content and not the content of subdomain. I'm using apache server, linux operating system.

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how SSL protocol works with the browsers. Whenever browsers receive HTTPS request for domain name, it first checks with the server then delivers the site's content. If a website on server has enabled SSL accessed with HTTPS, browser will try to make secure connection and send request to the server.

In your case, your main website is working properly with HTTP as well as HTTPS and delivers proper content, but your sub-domain is not showing proper content for HTTPS. In order to deliver proper content you should consult with your development team. You can better host your sub-domain on another server or you can protect your sub-domain with valid separate SSL certificate.

Suggestion: If you own multiple sub-domains then it is advisable to use Wildcard SSL, that can protect unlimited number of sub-domains with single certificates. Please note, this unlimited does secure first level (`blog.domain.com`), doesn't second-third-fourth-etc. level (`news.blog.domain.com, 1.news.blog.domain.com or abc.1.news.blog.domain.com`).

Comment: is it because of some configuration change while installing the ssl certificate. Which file i need to modify in order to solve this issue?

Comment: You should refer to [this article](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/install-ssl-certificate-on-apache-with-mod_ssl) to know whether you have made any mistakes while configuring SSL. You can also try uninstalling the certificate and configuring it again by following the instructions.